# How do I prevent annotation from getting clipped in apexcharts?

Tags: apexcharts

Codepen with code demonstrating the issue
https://codepen.io/haranrk-the-animator/pen/LYeLxOa?editors=1011

How do I restrict the actual graph to a smaller width? So, that the annotations do not get clipped?

[image: demo-img]

```
var options = {
  annotations: {
    yaxis: [
      {
        y: 8200,
        borderColor: "#00E396",
        label: {
          borderColor: "#00E396",
          style: {
            color: "#fff",
            background: "#00E396"
          },
          text: "Y Axis Annotation"
        }
      }
    ],
    xaxis: [
      {
        // in a datetime series, the x value should be a timestamp, just like it is generated below
        x: new Date("11/17/2017").getTime(),
        strokeDashArray: 0,
        borderColor: "#775DD0",
        label: {
          borderColor: "#775DD0",
          style: {
            color: "#fff",
            background: "#775DD0"
          },
          text: "X Axis Anno Vertical"
        }
      },
      {
        x: new Date("03 Dec 2017").getTime(),
        borderColor: "#FEB019",
        label: {
          borderColor: "#FEB019",
          style: {
            color: "#fff",
            background: "#FEB019"
          },
          orientation: "horizontal",
          text: "X Axis Anno Horizonal"
        }
      }
    ],
    points: [
      {
        x: new Date("07 Dec 2017").getTime(),
        y: 8500.9,
        marker: {
          size: 6,
          fillColor: "#fff",
          strokeColor: "#2698FF",
          radius: 2
        },
        label: {
          borderColor: "#FF4560",
          offsetY: 0,
          textAnchor: 'start',
          style: {
            color: "#fff",
            background: "#FF4560"
          },

          text: "Point Annotation (XY)"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  chart: {
    height: 380,
    type: "line",
    id: "areachart-2"
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  stroke: {
    curve: "straight"
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: series.monthDataSeries1.prices
    }
  ],
  title: {
    text: "Line with Annotations",
    align: "left"
  },
  labels: series.monthDataSeries1.dates,
  xaxis: {
    type: "datetime"
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really dont wany to change `textAnchor` to `'end'` or add `offsetX` try this

```
#chart {
  max-width: 650px;
}
#chart div svg{
  width: 700px !important;
}
```

Comment: This not work as the annotation is part of the SVG, so the annotation gets clipped